# htaccess weird trailing slash problem

Tags: .htaccess, slash, trailing

**url:** http://localhost/url/of/the/keyword/whatever/

```
RewriteRule ^url/of/the/keyword/([a-z]+)/?$ ?keyword=$1 [L]
```

```
// php  
echo $_GET['keyword'];    
// outputs **whatever** (OK)
```

```
RewriteRule ^url/of/the/keyword/(.*)/?$ ?keyword=$1 [L]
```

```
// php  
echo $_GET['keyword'];  
// outputs **whatever/** (with a trailing slash, which is not expected)
```

can anyone explain why there's a trailing slash for the second condition?

---

Also, how can I allow percentage sign in url rewrite?

http://localhost/url/of/the/keyword/%40%23%24/

```
RewriteRule ^url/of/the/keyword/([0-9a-zA-Z-.%])/?$ ?keyword=$1 [L]
```

the above rule doesn't work. can anyone correct this so it allows a-Z, 0-9, dot, hyphen, and percentage sign?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the `/` for the second `RewriteRule` because `.*` is greedy. That is to say it *greedily captures* the trailing slash because you've marked it as optional `/?`. It's best to be specific with your patterns (like the first `RewriteRule`) to avoid such situations.

The pattern you match can accept anything. Just remember it has to be a valid URL. The problem is you forgot the quantifier. So you're only matching one character from the grouping.

Add the `+`

```
RewriteRule ^url/of/the/keyword/([0-9a-zA-Z\-.%]+)/?$ ?keyword=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I got the first one. The second, it was a typo, I forgot the plus sign. But even with the plus sign, it doesn't work. Results in a 404.